# Grub boots into recovery mode

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

When I boot grub doesnt show up (only ubuntu installed) I would like grub to be shown for a second or 2 (shift doesnt seem to bring it up). My main problem is that grub boots into what i assume to be recovery mode, I can login as myself and startx but that is obviously a right pain. Could someone please advise me on how to remedy this problem?

Grub.cfg:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="1"
if [ ${prev_saved_entry} ]; then
  set saved_entry=${prev_saved_entry}
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z ${boot_once} ]; then
    saved_entry=${chosen}
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then if [ -z ${boot_once} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,6)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod vbe
  if terminal_output gfxterm ; then true ; else
    # For backward compatibility with versions of terminal.mod that don't
    # understand terminal_output
    terminal gfxterm
  fi
fi
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,6)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
set lang=en
insmod gettext
if [ ${recordfail} = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-25-generic root=UUID=1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba ro   quiet splash
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-25-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-25-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-25-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-25-generic root=UUID=1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-25-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-21-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic root=UUID=1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba ro   quiet splash
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-21-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-21-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic root=UUID=1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1cd98d8a-97b3-4f25-9da2-e7128ef6dcba
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
if [ ${timeout} != -1 ]; then
  if keystatus; then
    if keystatus --shift; then
      set timeout=-1
    else
      set timeout=0
    fi
  else
    if sleep --interruptible 3 ; then
      set timeout=0
    fi
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg` should not be edited directly. Instead, options like `GRUB_TIMEOUT` can be configured in `/etc/default/grub` Here's a sample of what that file looks like:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

`GRUB_DEFAULT` sets the default menu entry. For instance, `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` highlights the 1st menu entry. 1 would be the second. Perhaps a recovery session is set as the default?

On machines with only a single OS, like yours, `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` hides the menu. Make sure that this line is commented. If multiple OS's are present this setting is ignored. Also make sure the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value is greater than 0. This is the number of seconds before the default entry is automatically booted.

After any changes to `/etc/default/grub`make sure to run `sudo update-grub` to update your configuration.

More details can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. 
I disabled the recovery menu by doing the following:

Open `/etc/default/grub` with an editor

Add this line:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5
```

Update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

So the menu is only shown for 5 seconds and then the boot process continues.